# Delete view is returning null object to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to develop a simple application for realizing CRUD operations, but the Delete operation is having a strange problem when get back to the controller, because it returns a null object, not allowing the operation to complete. I'll show below the code for the model, controller and its respective view.

Model:

```
public class Biblioteca
{
    public int IdBiblioteca { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public class BibliotecaController : Controller
{
    ADAO dao = DAOFactory.GetInstance(DAOFactory.DAOType.Biblioteca);

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DeleteLibrary(int id)
    {
        return View(dao.Select(id));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteLibrary(Biblioteca b)
    {
        dao.Delete(b);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

View DeleteLibrary

```
@model BibliotecaWebApp.Models.Biblioteca

<h2>DeleteLibrary</h2>
<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>Biblioteca</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IdBiblioteca)</dt>
        <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IdBiblioteca)</dd>
        <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)</dt>
        <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nome)</dd>
        <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Endereco)</dt>
        <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Endereco)</dd>
    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

As we can see in the controller snippet, there are two controllers for each operation: a [HttpGet] which retrieve the data to be shown in a confirmation view, before the same can be deleted [HttpPost]. The problem arises in the [HttpPost]DeleteLibrary, once it gets a null Biblioteca object from the view to perform the exclusion. Below there are two screenshots that better presents this:

[HttpGet] DeleteLibrary works properly:

[image]

But when the user clicks in the Delete button, on the [HttpPost]DeleteLibrary method is received a null object, as shown below:

[image]

My question is: Why the returning object is getting null when it's passed to the view? What can be the problem?

Comment: Because your not generating any form controls for your model so there is nothing to post back. But you should only be posting back the `ID` property anyway.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I didn't understand what form is this, because in the view I've shown there is a form which realizes the post. What did you mean? Thanks.

Comment: A form only posts back the values of its controls (`input`, `select` and `textarea`). You have not controls so there is nothing to be submitted (and nor should you have). Just change the signature of your POST method to `[HttpPost](public ActionResult DeleteLibrary(int id)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this approach will create two methods with the same signature, [HttpGet] and [HttpPost]. What I can't understand is that the other CRUD methods worked that way. Isn't there another approach for this? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for asking too much. because some concepts of MVC I still cannot comprehend. What I'm not understading is there are two methods DeleteLibrary(int id) which opens the page for confirmation and the DeleteLibrary(Biblioteca b) which does the deletion itself. If I perform your suggestion, I'll have two methods with the same signature. Could you use my code to show what I have to do? Sorry again for my ignorance. Thanks.

Comment: If your change the signature of the POST method to `[HttpPost](public ActionResult DeleteLibrary(int id)` and click the submit button then the value of `id` in the method will be the value of the `IdBiblioteca` you sent to the view (assuming your using the default routes). Your `dao.Delete()`should really be accepting just an `ID` (not `Biblioteca`), but if you really want the method this way (and degrade performance) then you need to call the database and get the `Biblioteca` again (just as you did in the GET method)

Comment: Another option is to add a hidden input for each property in your model - `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IdBiblioteca)` etc inside the form tags, but that just degrades performance and opens you to over-posting attacks

Comment: Now I've understood. Thank you very much Stephen!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```html
**@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IdBiblioteca)
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    }**
```

instead of this

```html
**@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    }**
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so. Maybe you could describe what's different about the two blocks and why those changes fix the problem.

Comment: because of cache problems in local machine some data seems to be not bounded correctly. But, when we post a value inside form submit intentionally it works